# Instr Equivalent in perl?

Tags: perl

A variable named `RestrictedNames` holds the list of restricted user names. `SplitNames` is an array variable which holds the complete set of user name. Now I have to check whether current name is found in `RestrictedNames` variable like using `instr`.

```
@SplitNames = ("naag algates","arvind singh","abhay avasti","luv singh","new algates") and now i want to block all the surnames which has "singh" ,"algates" etc.

    @SplitNames = ("naag algates","arvind singh","abhay avasti","luv singh","new algates")
    $RestrictedNames="tiwary singh algates n2 n3 n4 n5 n6";
    for(my $i=0;$i<@SplitNames;$i++)
    {
        if($RestrictedNames =~ m/^$SplitNames[$i]/ ) //google'd this condition, still fails
        {
              print "$SplitNames[$i] is a restricted person";
        }
    }
```

Comment: BASIC's `instr` work-alikes are [`index`](http://p3rl.org/index) and [`rindex`](http://p3rl.org/rindex) in Perl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should modify this line:

```
if($RestrictedNames =~ m/^$SplitNames[$i]/ )
```

to

```
if($RestrictedNames =~ m/$SplitNames[$i]/ )
```

`^` looks for a match from the beginning.

For more details about perl metacharacters, see [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Metacharacters)

**EDIT:**
If you need blocking based on surnames, try this code in the for-loop body.

```
my @tokens = split(' ', $SplitNames[$i]); # splits name on basis of spaces
my $surname = $tokens[$#tokens]; # takes the last token
if($RestrictedNames =~ m/$surname/ )
{
      print "$SplitNames[$i] is a restricted person\n";
}
```

Comment: What result you expect?, Following is the example I used
`$RestrictedNames="n1 n2";
@SplitNames = ('n1', 'n2', 'n3');`
Output: n1, n2

Comment: yes i forgot to provide you the data for @SplitNames! @SplitNames = ("naag algates","arvind singh","abhay avasti","luv singh") and now i want to block all the surnames which has "singh". Actually i want a result where "arvind singh" and "luv singh" are under restricted names.

Answer (score 4):

Don't try dealing with a string of restricted names, deal with an array.

Then just use [the smart match operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) (`~~` or two tilde characters) to see if a given string is in it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $RestrictedNames="n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 n7 n8 n9";
my @restricted_names = split " ", $RestrictedNames;
say "You can't have foo" if 'foo' ~~ @restricted_names;
say "You can't have bar" if 'bar' ~~ @restricted_names;
say "You can't have n1" if 'n1' ~~ @restricted_names;
say "You can't have n1a" if 'n1a' ~~ @restricted_names;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like below using Hash Slice:

```
my @users =  ( "n10", "n12", "n13", "n4", "n5" );
my @r_users = ( "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5", "n6", "n7", "n8", "n9" ) ;
my %check;
@check{@r_users}  = ();
foreach my $user ( @users ) {
   if ( exists $check{$user} ) {
      print"Restricted User: $user  \n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most idiomatic way would be to create a hash of the restricted names, then split the surname from the name and check if the surname is in the hash.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @SplitNames = ("naag algates","arvind singh","abhay avasti","luv singh","new algates");
my $RestrictedNames = "tiwar y singh algates n2 n3 n4 n5 n6";

# Create hash of restricted names
my %restricted;
map { $restricted{$_}++ } split(' ', $RestrictedNames);

# Loop over names and check if surname is in the hash
for my $name (@SplitNames) {
    my $surname = (split(' ', $name))[-1];
    if ( $restricted{$surname} ) {
        print "$name is a restricted person\n";
    }
}
```

Please note that the `split` function normally takes a RegEx. However using `' '` with split is a special case. It splits on any length of whitespace, and also ignores any leading whitespace, so it's useful for splitting strings of individual words.

FYI, the equivalent to `instr` in perl is to use `index($string, $substring)`. If `$substring` does not occur inside `$string` it will return `-1`. Any other value means `$string` contains `$substring`. However, when comparing lists it's much less hassle to use a hash like I have shown above... and unlike index, it won't match 'joyce' when you really only meant to match 'joy'.

Comment: +1 for at last having answered the question in title, as all others keep suggest other ways (while it may be justified to help the requestor about his actual problem)